# Strange character issue

Tags: sql-server, encoding, character-encoding, sybase, linked-server

We have a linked server (in SQL Server) that connects to Sybase database. We have also a job that transfer data from Sybase via the linked server and writes to a SQL Server database.

The problem is while transferring data from Sybase to SQL Server, it converts `£` to `œ`. The SQL Server collation being used is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

I tried all possible server options in linked server properties such as `Use Remote Collation`, `Collation Compatible` etc. but no joy.

When I fetch the data through the Interactive SQL (that is Sybase tool), data is displayed properly.

I do not know what else I can do, please help.

Comment: What is the database collation for source and destination DBs

Comment: issue is in the encoding side.what type of encoding you use?

Comment: What encoding/char set/code point are you using for the destination?  Can the Sybase database represent the pound symbol (£)?

Comment: SQL Server's collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, but no idea about Sybase side. But, Sybase holds correct value.

Comment: Use **sp_helpsort** to find the Character set of the Sybase server.  It's likely a Character set mismatch between the two databases.

Comment: Here what it returned is:  
Character Set = 2, cp850
    Code Page 850 (Multilingual) character set.
Sort Order = 50, bin_cp850
    Binary ordering, for use with Code Page 850 (cp850).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is code page issue as the guys stated above. I changed the collation that contains code page 850 which is same with sybase one and it is fixed.